# In An Asp.net MVC Pgroject Use Entity Framework to Connect different Oracle TableSpace

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework, multi-tenant

As the title , I had try to solve an Asp.net Problem that I have Using asp.net mvc and Entity Framework 4.1 in my project , and now I want to use EF to connect different TableSpace in Just only one oracle instance , but now I have a problem that I didn't kown how to use Entity Framework to Connection Different TableSpace in an oracle instance in an MultiTenancy Asp.Net MVC Project , I had tried to config multiple ConnectionString in Web.config file ,and they have different username and password to connect different oracle tablespace ,just like below:

ConnectionString "MyDBModel1"

```
<add name="MyDBModel1" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EntityModels.MyDBModel1.csdl|res://*/EntityModels.MyDBModel1.csdl.ssdl|res://*/EntityModels.MyDBModel1.msl;provider=Oracle.DataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=ORCL;PASSWORD=123456;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=MyDBModel1&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

ConnectioString "MyDBModel2"

```
<add name="MyDBModel2" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EntityModels.MyDBModel2.csdl|res://*/EntityModels.MyDBModel2.csdl.ssdl|res://*/EntityModels.MyDBModel2.msl;provider=Oracle.DataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=ORCL;PASSWORD=123456;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=MyDBModel2&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

but the EF DataModel already had specific configuration key name ,just like

```
/// <summary>
    /// Initalize New  MyDBModel1 Object
    /// </summary>
    public MyDBModel1() : base("name=MyDBModel1", "MyDBModel1")
    {
        this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        OnContextCreated();
    }
```

As we have seen，it had assign the ConnectionString key name is "MyDBModel1", and here I have not find a way to use the ConnectString that name is  "MyDBModel2" at the same time .This is All My Question , Maybe I think it is not very clear when I ask describe this question ，and thanks for you help .

Answer (score 0):

From your question I understand the requirement of accessing different table spaces. There is no mention on either you want to achieve this for a single user or under which context. However I am suggesting the following.
1. You identify the context under which you will have to switch the table spaces. Like each tenant has his own table space.
2. You have an option of passing the `EntityConnection` as a  parameter when you initialize your ccontextbin your data access logic. 
3. Based on your identification of the user /tenant, you will have to pass in the connection string in the `EntityConnection` object. This way you can switch between different connection strings at run time. The point is the identification of the table space and the user / tenant association.